# Error: Incorrect syntax near ')' while executing ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, .net

i just want to save details, but the code of function is giving error pls help. the code i have is:-

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(Dal.conMain)
        Dim x As String = ""
        Try
            Dim str As String = "insert into company_master(unqid, jurisdiction, company_name, tag_line, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Pan_No, STR_No)"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jurisdiction", _jurisdiction)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_name", _company_name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tag_Line", _tag_Line)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address_Line1", _Address_Line1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address_Line2", _Address_Line2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pan_No", _Pan_No)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str_No", _str_No)
            con.Open()
            x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString()
            con.Close()
            If x = "" Or x = "0" Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
```

Comment: the error was "incorrect syntax near ')'". that encountered while executing executenonquery()

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that your SQL is incomplete. SQL insert statements should be

```
insert into <tablename> (col1, col2) values (@col1, @col2);
```

you only have the first part of that in your code, ie:

```
insert into <tablename> (col1, col2);
```

add in the placeholder for the parameters and you should be fine.

Comment: no problem. If this is the answer, please remember to mark it as such and if helpful please also press the ^ to mark it as useful